# Displaying duplicates in a list (no code)

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, no-code-solution

I have multiple columns in a SharePoint list and I need to group the list by displaying only items that have duplicates.

Basically if two or more records have the same `Invoice number` I want it to display the invoice number with the number of times it occurs in the list.

I need a no code solution.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a view.

1. Create custom view
2. In group by section, select Invoice number Column
3. In total section. select count infront of Invoice number column
4. Done.

Disadvantage is, you will also see items which are not duplicate. I dont think any no code solution is available besides this.

Answer (score 1):

You may use Grouping on the list. This will not only group invoices of the same number but also show the total count. One limitation of this is that it will still group items with no duplicates and show a total of 1.

To do this, follow the following steps:

1. Open the list.
2. On the ribbon bar, click List tab.
3. Select Modify View.
4. Expand Group By tab.
5. Fill up the "First group by the column" with your Invoice Number.
6. Click OK to save.

[image]